# ¿Como aplicar un Style a un botón en styles.xml en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Quiero aplicar este estilo a todos los botones de mi app

```
<style name="button_dark"  parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_red_press</item>
</style>
```

Lo agregue en el tema de la siguiente manera

```
<style name="Theme.Math" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/nook</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ok</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button_dark</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Pero no se aplica el estilo, el xml drawable es este

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red_press"/>
</selector>
```

Y estos son los otros dos

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/but" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
<stroke
    android:color="@color/but_stroke"
    android:width="1dp" />
</shape>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/but_press" />
<corners android:radius="40dp" />
<stroke
    android:color="@color/but_stroke_press"
    android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal y como puede hacer para arreglarlo?

Aca es codigo del botón
Esta en el activity_main

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/main_button_jugar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="Jugar"
    android:text="@string/bt_jugar"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_textView_bestScore"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Quiero aclarar que estuve buscando por horas una solucion, corregi codigo, hice muchos intentos de prueba y error, segui leyendo e investigando pero es todos lados recomiendan que lo haga asi, pero el problma persiste.

Comment: ¿Y en el botón, cuándo lo asignas? Porque en tu código no se ve asignado

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Ahi agregue el codigo del boton, no quiero agregarle el estilo directamente, si no que lo tome desde el tema

Comment: Disculpa una demora, a tu `style` ¿lo agregas a tu manifest?

Comment: muestra tu manifest

Comment: Acabo de probar tu código y funciona perfecto, lo he probado con otros colores y funciona.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Si, lo agregaba al manifest, ya encontre el eroor, era un bug que no tomaba el tema, ahora el problema que tengo es que cuando el cambio el tema desde el main con la funcion setTheme al iniciar de nuevo la activity se vuelve al tema original,ademas que no cambia el tema de las otras activitys

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo pero todavia estoy probando unas cosas, creo que lo voy a poder solucionar

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Gracias de todas formas :D

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema y efectivamente ahorra bastante tiempo si se aplican estilos en el Theme, me funciona el esquema que muestras para EditText y TextView con los items editTextStyle y android:textViewStyle pero no para el Button con el item buttonStyle o android:buttonStyle. Espero encontremos la solución.

Answer (score 0):

primero digamos que este archivo drawable que tiene los selectors se llama button_background

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red_press"/>
</selector>
```

Entonces crea un estilo con el nombre TuEstilo (cambia a un nombre que tu quieras)

```
<style name="TuEstilo" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_background</item>
</style>
```

Y luego en los botones agrega el siguiente atributo: `style="@style/TuEstilo"`

```
<Button
    style="@style/TuEstilo"
    android:id="@+id/main_button_jugar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="Jugar"
    android:text="@string/bt_jugar"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_textView_bestScore"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: de esa forma me funcionaba correctamente, lo que yo traba de lograr es tener varios estilos de botones y que cambien de acuerdo al tema seleccionado, porque queria que el estilo se aplica desde el theme y no tener que ir poniendo uno por uno

Comment: ahhh, si o si debes crear tus estilos y asignarlos de manera manual. Yo siempre los creo desde el comienzo del desarrollo y luego solo agrego la linea porque en mi estilo no solo pongo el background, pongo que font, tamaño de letra, el color de la letra. De esa manera esas lineas ya no las pongo en el xml del layout y me ahorro tiempo :D