# ¿Porqué el style no se aplica a todos los EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml, android-layout

Tengo definido un tema el cual incluye un style para los EditText entre otros, pero solo se aplica a algunos EditText, por ejemplo, en el del main activity no se aplica, pero en el de otra activity si, me fije en el xml de los EditText y son exactamentes igual a excepcion de tamaños y texto

Este es el Theme que cree:

```
<style name="ThemeMath" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_6</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/button</item>
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/editTextM</item>
    <item name="android:switchStyle" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@style/sw</item>
</style>
```

Este es el Style:

```
<style name="editTextM" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edittxt_m</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
</style>
```

Y este el drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:thickness="0dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/teal_200" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/text"/>
    <corners android:radius="40dp" />
</shape>
```

Este es en el que no se aplica:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/main_textView_nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:autofillHints=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/txt_nombre"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/main_button_jugar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Y este es al que si se aplica:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/niveles_textView_resultado"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/resultado"
        android:inputType="numberSigned|textPersonName|numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cl_resultado"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Hola, no habías resuelto el problema? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401304/como-aplicar-un-style-a-un-bot%c3%b3n-en-styles-xml-en-android-studio

Comment: @Elenasys esa pregunta era porque no lograba que se aplique a ningun boton, resulto ser un error bobo, pero el error que tengo ahora es que el estilo se aplica para algunos edit tex, y en otros no, y estoy usando el mismo tema en toda la app, ademas que en la vista previa del xml, la parte de desing, si aparece con el estilo, pero al momento de ejecutarlo en un celular toma el estilo por defento